# How to containerize C# OpenTelemetry server

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, open-telemetry

I followed [Microsoft's tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-collection) on collecting metrics and it works fine. Then I wanted to containerize the example, but I can't get that to work. The `GET /metrics` endpoint on the dotnet server responds with

```
(52) Empty reply from server
```

I've narrowed it down to just the containerization of the dotnet application (so I'm disregarding the Prometheus and Grafana parts of the tutorial for now, I just want the `/metrics` endpoint on the dotnet server to respond with metrics).

---

That is, if I run:

- `dotnet run`
- `curl localhost:9184/metrics`

then I get expected output (`... hats_sold_Hats 12 ...`).

But if I do

- `docker run -ditp 9184:9184 $(docker build -q .)`
- `curl localhost:9184/metrics`

I get `(52) Empty reply from server`, whereas I expected a number of hats sold.

---

What I'm concluding is that the OpenTelemetry server *is* reached, it just responds differently. Now, if I attach a shell to the docker container and run the `curl` command I get expected output again, so it seems as though the OpenTelemetry server is somehow aware (presumably http headers) of whether it's called from the same machine or from a different one.

#### What I've done already

- I am relatively experienced with docker and networking and there are many pitfalls in opening ports etc, and I've double+ checked, but I don't think that's going on here. Still I feel like this problem lies in the domain of what I don't know about docker.
- I've looked through the source
- I've looked in the source code of the `PrometheusExporter`, `System.Net.HttpListener` and `MeterProviderSdk` to see if there was anything I could do about it, but I don't see it. There's tracings littered there but they aren't of help either.
- I've noticed that the Opentelemetry server doesn't error if the port it's going to listen on is already taken; it just silently doesn't listen. So I double check that.
- I've tried to host both processes in 2 containers through docker-compose but I can't get that to work either.
- The opposite scenario where I `curl` from within a container to the dotnet server running on the host, I need to proxy and insert a `Host: localhost` header otherwise I get a `400`. So the dotnet server is definitely very picky in what it accepts.
- I wait sufficiently to ensure there are metrics: if there aren't any yet, the empty response would be correct. But outside the container the response is still empty while inside the container it already responds with metrics.

---

#### Question:

Why does the OpenTelemetry server from outside the container respond with an empty reply, but from within the container it just responds with the metrics?

---

### Minimal example:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus" Version="1.3.0-rc.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Program.cs verbatim from the tutorial:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;
using System.Threading;
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;

class Program
{
    static Meter s_meter = new Meter("HatCo.HatStore", "1.0.0");
    static Counter<int> s_hatsSold = s_meter.CreateCounter<int>(name: "hats-sold", 
                                                                unit: "Hats",
                                                                description: "The number of hats sold in our store");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using MeterProvider meterProvider = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
                .AddMeter("HatCo.HatStore")
                .AddPrometheusExporter(opt =>
                {
                    opt.StartHttpListener = true;
                    opt.HttpListenerPrefixes = new string[] { $"http://localhost:9184/" };
                    
                })
                .Build();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        while (true) // !Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            // Pretend our store has a transaction each second that sells 4 hats
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            s_hatsSold.Add(4);
            Console.WriteLine("Sold hats");
        }
    }
}
```

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build
CMD [ "dotnet", "run" ]
# and a dockerignore with `bin, obj, .vs`
```

Comment: I had the issues and have given up.  I'm trying to go down the otel-collector route now.